# Update a row with specific ID in Esqueleto

Tags: haskell, persistent, esqueleto

I can change a field of a row with `entryId` in Esqueleto like this:

```
  update $ \entry -> do
    set entry [ EntryFoo =. val bar ]
    where_ (entry ^. EntryId ==. val entryId)
```

However, writing it all the time gets annoying. I'd like to be able to write something like this:

```
  updateById entryId $ \entry ->
    set entry [ EntryFoo =. val bar ]
```

I tried to write this helper by myself, but found that I don't know how to write `^. EntryId` in a generic way (i.e. a way that would work for any entry types). Is it possible? Or am I missing something and `updateById` already exists in Esqueleto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any `Entity`, `^. EntityId` can be written as `^. persistIdField` (the `persistIdField` field is a method of the `PersistEntity` class). Thus, your function can be written like this:

```
updateById
  :: (E.PersistEntityBackend val ~ E.SqlBackend,
      MonadIO m, E.PersistEntity val)
  => Key val
  -> (E.SqlExpr (E.Entity val) -> E.SqlQuery a)
  -> E.SqlWriteT m ()
updateById entryId upd = E.update $ \entry -> do
  upd entry
  E.where_ (entry E.^. E.persistIdField ==. E.val entryId)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am definitely no expert on esqueleto, but I would guess:

```
updateById entryId upd = update $ \entry -> do
                           upd entry
                           where_ (entry ^. EntryId ==. val entryId)
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: Sure, it solves the problem for one particular table (`Entry`), but I want a solution that would work for any table. I.e. I need `updateById :: Key a -> _ -> _`, while your function is `updateById :: Key Entry -> _ -> _`.